# Localhost Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, xampp

Whenever I search for https://localhost in chrome in Windows OS it will show the folders/files but when I do the same in Ubuntu it will show the XAMPP welcome page.
How can I get the same in Ubuntu as in Windows settings?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779267/2782188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAMPP page that you see is because you have a file called index.htm or index.php in your root directory, and probably it's the only .html or .php file so you see it.
If you remove that file you will see the folders and files in your working directory.

Tip: Maybe it's better for you to install LAMP Stack to more control on your work. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: how can I delete that index.php

Comment: check this directory /opt/lampp/htdocs

Comment: but I am unable to delete it

Comment: Well, you need to change the permessions of the folder.
check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files

Comment: thx that worked well.